# How to check if two rotated images overlap in javafx

Tags: java, algorithm, javafx

I have two ImageViews in a javafx program. They both have been rotated and translated a few times. I know their initial angle and position (layoutX,layoutY) and I also have the list of transformation and rotation they went through. How can I tell if they are overlapping one another right now or not?

The images are given below:

**Image of an Apple:**

[image: Image of an Apple]

**Image of an Arrow:**
[image: Image of an Arrow]

It would also be really helpful if I could determine whether the tip of the arrow is inside the apple image. However, its okay if I can just tell if the images are colliding or not.

The apple Class:

```
class Apple {

    public double height, width, x1, x2, y1, y2;
    public ImageView image;

    Apple(double x1, double y1, double height, double width) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    Apple(double x1, double y1) {
        height = 20;
        width = 20;
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
    }

    public boolean isCollision(double ax, double ay) {
        x2 = x1 + width;
        y2 = y1 + height;
        if (ax > x1 && ax < x2 && ay > y1 && ay < y2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The code to create apples:

```
Apple generateApple() {
    double x1, y1, rx, ry;
    x1 = 300;
    y1 = 250;
    rx = 150;
    ry = 150;

    double xa, ya;
    xa = randomno(x1, x1 + rx);
    ya = randomno(y1, y1 + ry);
    Apple apl = new Apple(xa, ya);
    createAppleImage(apl);
    return apl;
}

void createAppleImage(Apple apple) {
    ImageView appleImage = null;
    FileInputStream inputstream5 = null;
    try {
        inputstream5 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\MAHDI\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ThreadTesting\\apple.jpg");
        Image img4 = new Image(inputstream5);

        appleImage = new ImageView(img4);
        appleImage.setFitHeight(apple.height);
        appleImage.setFitWidth(apple.width);
        appleImage.setLayoutX(apple.x1);
        appleImage.setLayoutY(apple.y1);
        System.out.println(" " + apple.x1 + " " + apple.y1);
        gameLayout.getChildren().add(appleImage);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AppleShooter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            inputstream5.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AppleShooter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    apple.image = appleImage;
}
```

The code to create arrow:

```
    FileInputStream inputstream3 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\MAHDI\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ThreadTesting\\arrowpic.png");
    Image img2 = new Image(inputstream3);
    arrow = new ImageView(img2);
    arrow.setFitHeight(arrowheight);
    arrow.setFitWidth(arrowwidth);
    arrow.setLayoutX(40);
    arrow.setLayoutY(420);
    arrow.setRotate(-45);
```

Comment: I would look at [`Node#intersects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#intersects-javafx.geometry.Bounds-)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start by having a look at [`Shape.intersects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#intersect-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-)

I would also like to add that I know absolutely nothing about JavaFX and basically hobbled this together from reading the JavaDocs and some other examples

[image: Rotate]

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
        box1.setFill(Color.RED);

        Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(120, 10, 100, 100);
        box2.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(box1);
        root.getChildren().add(box2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 230, 120);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(60, new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            private double delta1 = 0.5;
            private double delta2 = -5;

            private double angle1 = 0;
            private double angle2 = 0;

            private Shape oldCollision;

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                angle1 += delta1;
                angle2 += delta2;
                box1.setRotate(angle1);
                box2.setRotate(angle2);

                if (oldCollision != null) {
                    root.getChildren().remove(oldCollision);
                    oldCollision = null;
                }

                Shape collision = Shape.intersect(box1, box2);
                if (collision != null) {
                    collision.setFill(Color.AQUA);
                    root.getChildren().add(collision);
                }
                oldCollision = collision;

//              if (box1.intersects(box1.parentToLocal(box2.getBoundsInParent()))) {
//                  box1.setFill(Color.AQUA);
//                  box2.setFill(Color.AQUA);
//              } else {
//                  box1.setFill(Color.RED);
//                  box2.setFill(Color.BLUE);
//              }
            }
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I just want to point out that adding and removing the `collision` `Shape` is for demonstration purposes only!

Now before you point out to me how `Rectangle` is not `ImageView`, make sure you take the time to have read of the JavaDocs for [`ImageView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) and [`Rectangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html) for the reasons why I choose it for this example

Comment: The problem here: Bounds are aligned with the coordinate axis. The bounds of a rotated rect are actually bigger than the bounds of a unrotated rect. Furthermore `intersects` expects the coordinates to be in it's local coordinate system...

Comment: I don't think it does. Just before the rects turn aqua there seems to be a frame where the rects intersect but are not colored aqua. Also you treated a very special case (center with the same `y` value, synchronous rotation.)

Comment: @fabian First, thanks for the note about local coordinate space, updated. Second, the animation been played in the gif is life 8 fps - it's not a true representation of the animation. I set the `Duration` to half a second and only saw the `Rectangle`s change color when they touched. However, your third point has smacked me in the face :( - got a better idea?

Comment: @fabian Okay - Found `Shape.intersect`, this is what I was looking for!